# Sunspot Solr error on rake sunspot:index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-solr

I am trying to use Sunspot gem for Solr on a Rails 3 app.  I have followed RailsCast #278, since I am using Windows I have to do rake sunspot:solr:run and that seems to start with no error.  However when I try to run rake sunspot:reindex I get the error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
```

I am using mysql2 gem for mysql.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to do rake sunspot:solr:run and that seems to start with no error

It sounds like the connection is not being accepted at all to Solr, so this part is my first suspicion — you should get a lot of fairly verbose output from Solr when starting it. Can you share some output of that?

Also, what version of java are you running? (`java -version`)

Comment: Yes, heres the output when I start it.  I start it in one window, then try to do the index in another window.  Im using Java 1.6.0_24                          Gabe M@RGM1 /c/rails32/pa02
$ RAILS_ENV=development rake sunspot:solr:run
java version "1.6.0_24"
org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent inform      
INFO: JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
INFO: solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
2012-06-11 21:32:50.959::INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8983

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex" on Windows. The solution is to add the correct RAILS_ENV option, for me it was test, e.g.

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=test
```

Yes, you'll have to have solr server running beforehand:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run RAILS_ENV=test
```